# Initialize DirectX 11 using 'SwapChainPanel' in C#, UWP, XAML

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, directx-11

So, my issue is that I do not know how to get an 'IntPtr' or something of the sort from a 'SwapChainPanel' in UWP. I am trying to make a DirectX 11 application using the popular 'SharpDX' binding set, but I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

Here's my code:

```
public static void Initialize(SwapChainPanel panel)
{
    FeatureLevel[] featureLevels =
    [
        FeatureLevel.Level_11_1,
        FeatureLevel.Level_11_0
    ];

    SwapChainDescription swapChainDescription = new()
    {
        BufferCount = 1,
        ModeDescription = new((int)panel.ActualWidth, (int)panel.ActualHeight, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
        Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        IsWindowed = true,
        SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
        Flags = SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch
    };

    SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, featureLevels, swapChainDescription, out device, out swapChain);

    using (var dxgiDevice2 = device.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device2>())
    {
        using Adapter dxgiAdapter = dxgiDevice2.Adapter;
        using Factory2 dxgiFactory2 = dxgiAdapter.GetParent<Factory2>();

        SwapChain swapChain1 = new(dxgiFactory2, device, swapChainDescription);

        panel.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            panel.SwapChain = swapChain1.QueryInterface<ISwapChainPanelNative>(); //<-- Error here
        }).AsTask().Wait();
    }

    using (var backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<Texture2D>(0))
    {
        renderTargetView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
    }

    device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(renderTargetView);
    device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, (int)panel.ActualWidth, (int)panel.ActualHeight));
}
```

And now trying a different approach, If I were to try and get a window handle:

```
private static IntPtr GetInteropWindowHandle(this SwapChainPanel panel)
{
    IInspectable interop = (IInspectable)panel;

    object interopObj = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(interop.NativePointer); //<-- Error here
    IntPtr windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (interopObj is PropertySet propertySet)
    {
        if (propertySet.TryGetValue("SwapChainInteropHandle", out object value))
            windowHandle = (IntPtr)value;
    }
    return windowHandle;
}
```

And the way I would use the above:

```
SwapChainDescription swapChainDescription = new()
{
    BufferCount = 1,
    ModeDescription = new((int)panel.ActualWidth, (int)panel.ActualHeight, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    OutputHandle = panel.GetInteropWindowHandle()
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    IsWindowed = true,
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
    Flags = SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch
};
```

I tried using ChatGPT 4, and looking on the SharpDX forums, and looking at Microsoft Learn, but alas, I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: How do you define ISwapChainPanelNative exactly in .NET? ISwapChainPanelNative should be queried from the swapChainPanel, not the swapChain